# How do I pass eslint's "prefer-destructuring" rule if I'm assigning two variables based off an object in a specific index of an array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, destructuring

I have array touchEvents. It looks like:

```
evt: {
    touchEvents: [
       {
         clientX: 3,
         clientY: 4,
       }, {...}, ...
    ]
 }
```

I wanted to reassign two variables to the two properties specifically in the `[0]` position of the array.

I did:

```
clientX = evt.touchEvents[0].clientX;
clientY = evt.touchEvents[0].clientY;
```

The eslint linter said:

> error: Use object destructuring (prefer-destructuring)

So I did:

```
({ clientX, clientY } = evt.touchEvents[0]);
```

And I got the error

> error: Use array destructuring (prefer-destructuring)

I don't understand how to use "array destructuring" to assign these variables. I've read the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and the [eslint documentation on destructuring](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring) but I still don't understand what it wants of me, or rather, how to use array destructuring to assign these variables.

**How can I use "array destructuring" to pass this eslint rule and assign my variables?**

Comment: Perhaps you're after: `const {touchEvents: [{clientX, clientY}]} = evt;` ?

Comment: Shouldn't `.touches` be `.touchEvents`?

Comment: Have you tried `[{ clientX, clientY }] = evt.touchEvents;` ? Don't know why your lint is complaining, `{ clientX, clientY } = evt.touches[0];` looks pretty fine to me.

Comment: You might want to simply disable that rule (setting its `array` config to `false`)

Comment: @Hao I will try that when i'm back on my computer, but will that guarantee it'll grab the element [0]?

Comment: @Barmar I didn't copy/paste the code, just banged it out by hand as an example.

Comment: Obviously it was a typo. No need to reply, just fix it.

Comment: @CalebJay Yes, since the object destructuring is on the first element of the array destructuring. If you want to destruct the second one, do `[_, { clientX, clientY }] = evt.touchEvents;` instead, but that's too crazy and hard to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in two lines it would be

```
const [ touchEvents ] = evt.touchEvents
const { clientX, clientY } = touchEvents
```

or one-liners

```
const { clientX, clientY } = evt.touchEvents[0]
```

or

```
const [{ clientX, clientY }] = evt.touchEvents
```

if you feel any rule bothers you, you can always disable with `// eslint-disable-next-line <the-rule-name>`

Comment: The first snippet doesn't work. That accesses `evt[0]` directly.

Comment: true, I misread the object. Updated (although now it's a bit redundant)